# никак не могу понять почему не работает стрельба в этом коде( полное отсутствие реакции на пробел)

Tags: python

```
import sys 
import random 
import pygame
  
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))
display_width = 1280 
display_height = 800
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Units = pygame.image.load('C:/Python36-32/mygame1py/.idea/units.png')
fon = pygame.image.load('C:/Python36-32/mygame1py/starfiel.png')
Units.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
units = []
#mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
ind = 0
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets =  pygame.sprite.Group()#[]
def Sekadr(level, wid, wcadr, hcadr, imagename, listname):
    for y in range(level):
      for x in range(int(wid/ wcadr)):
          listname.append(imagename.subsurface(x * wcadr, y * hcadr, wcadr, hcadr))
Sekadr(15, 800, 40, 40, Units, units)
xwingImg = units[0]#pg.image.load('X-Wing.bmp').convert()
tieImg = units[20]  #pg.image.load('tiefighter.png').convert()
space = units[50]#pg.image.load('C:/Python36-32/mygame1py/.idea/priroda-6.png')
xbullet = units[166] #pg.image.load('bullet.png').convert()units[166]
BG_image = pygame.image.load('C:/Python36-32/mygame1py/starfiel.png')

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image = filename
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = display_width / 2
        self.rect.bottom = display_height - 10
        self.speedx = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[ pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -8
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 8
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        if keystate[ pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -8
        if keystate[ pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 8
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.right > display_width:
            self.rect.right = display_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top-30,units[18], -10)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullets.add(bullet)

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(display_width - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > display_height - 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or self.rect.right > display_width + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(display_width - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-10, 100)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y,filename,speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((5, 5))
        self.image = filename
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedy = speed

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        #if self.rect.bottom < 0 or  self.rect.top > 570:
            #self.kill()
def main():
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()  # []
    mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(units[ind])
    all_sprites.add(player)
    for i in range(5):
        m = Mob()
        all_sprites.add(m)
        mobs.add(m)

    running = True
    f = 1
    while running:
        #player.shoot()
        clock.tick(20)
        screen.blit(fon, (0, 0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
          elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()
        all_sprites.update()
        hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullets, True, True)
        if hits: # and Mob()== dr():
           f = 0
        #all_sprites.update()
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)
        if hits:
           running = False
        #screen.blit(fon, (0, 0))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    #pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: отвратительный заголовок вопроса, отсутствие самого вопроса в теле сообщения.

Comment: да нормальный вопрос 'почему player.shoot() не работает?'